# IntelliJ scrolls after find

Tags: intellij-idea

After doing a Find (control/command-F), IntelliJ scrolls to what appears to be the *next* occurrence. This behavior can be annoying when using Find to highlight all occurrences as it will scroll to the next occurrence which can be many screens below.

Example:

1. Highlight "foo"
2. Command-F
3. IntelliJ moves to next occurrence of "foo", not the one I selected

Is there a way to disable this behavior? In other words, either don't scroll to next occurrence, or just go to the current occurrence.

Comment: Are you hitting Return after you find your occurrences?